# What will happen if the argument of mix() or clamp() is above 1 or below 0?

Tags: shaders, glsl, hlsl, interpolation

There's two magnificent intrisincs: `mix()` in GLSL and `clamp()` in HLSL, which are used to implement linear interpolation. Let's say we have a variable:

```
float v = ?; // where ? can be [-FLOAT_MAX, +FLOAT_MAX]
```

and then we do:

```
gl_FragColor = mix(value1, value2, v);
```

So, the question is: does it works the correct way under GL or DirectX? Should I EXPLICITLY normalize the value of v like this:

```
gl_FragColor = mix(value1, value2, clamp(v, 0.0, 1.0));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [The return value is computed as `x*(1−a)+y*a`.](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/mix.xhtml)

in other words if `a` is -1 then the result will be `2*x-y`

Comment: A `mix` is a linear interpolation between `x` and `y` when `a` is between 0 and 1. Outside of that domain it's an linear extrapolation.